# Web view setAppCachePath not working android

Tags: java, android, caching, webview

I want to  setAppCachePath() path to check  later which urls are cached & which are not before loading them. If there is no internet and the url is not cached I want to skip loading it.

```
 File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Android/data/" +
 if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
     }
        Log.i("cache",dir.getPath());

  wv.getSettings().setAppCachePath(dir.getPath());
```

> But, the cache folder is created & remains empty all the time .I think
>   webview is caching the urls on its default location only. How can this
>   be solved

I tried http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/saving-the-android-webview-cache-on-the-sd-card/ solution but this is also not working

I have gone through to :
[Check if url is cached webview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627916/check-if-url-is-cached-webview-android)

[WebView Cache Data Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206481/webview-cache-data-directory)

[Saving External Cache Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435633/saving-external-cache-files)

[How to move webView cache to SD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389002/how-to-move-webview-cache-to-sd)

[Check if file already exists in webview cache android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388989/check-if-file-already-exists-in-webview-cache-android)

Comment: If that does not work maybe you can override the `WebViewClient.shouldOverrideLoadingUrl()` and then cache the content in a background thread yourself.

Comment: Can you please share how I cache of url can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a work around if that method is not working.

Here is a possible solution:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(context);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         makeGetRequestAndCacheResult(String url);
         return false;
    }
});
```